# These summary statements seem contradictory, or have I misunderstood something?

Tags: causalimpact

So here's the output summary I got when running an analysis.

> This means that, although it may look as though the intervention has exerted a negative effect on the response variable when considering the intervention period as a whole, **this effect is not statistically significant, and so cannot be meaningfully interpreted.** The apparent effect could be the result of random fluctuations that are unrelated to the intervention. This is often the case when the intervention period is very long and includes much of the time when the effect has already worn off. It can also be the case when the intervention period is too short to distinguish the signal from the noise. Finally, failing to find a significant effect can happen when there are not enough control variables or when these variables do not correlate well with the response variable during the learning period.
>
> The probability of obtaining this effect by chance is very small (Bayesian one-sided tail-area probability p = 0.031). **This means the causal effect can be considered statistically significant**.

Is there supposed to be a difference between the two statements?

.

For more context:

[image]

And the entire summary report:

> During the post-intervention period, the response variable had an
> average value of approx. 17.70. In the absence of an intervention, we
> would have expected an average response of 19.69. The 95% interval of
> this counterfactual prediction is [17.62, 22.94]. Subtracting this
> prediction from the observed response yields an estimate of the causal
> effect the intervention had on the response variable. This effect is
> -1.99 with a 95% interval of [-5.24, 0.081]. For a discussion of the significance of this effect, see below.
>
> Summing up the individual data points during the post-intervention
> period (which can only sometimes be meaningfully interpreted), the
> response variable had an overall value of 247.80. Had the intervention
> not taken place, we would have expected a sum of 275.72. The 95%
> interval of this prediction is [246.67, 321.15].
>
> The above results are given in terms of absolute numbers. In relative
> terms, the response variable showed a decrease of-10%. The 95%
> interval of this percentage is [-27%, +0%].
>
> This means that, although it may look as though the intervention has
> exerted a negative effect on the response variable when considering
> the intervention period as a whole, this effect is not statistically
> significant, and so cannot be meaningfully interpreted. The apparent
> effect could be the result of random fluctuations that are unrelated
> to the intervention. This is often the case when the intervention
> period is very long and includes much of the time when the effect has
> already worn off. It can also be the case when the intervention period
> is too short to distinguish the signal from the noise. Finally,
> failing to find a significant effect can happen when there are not
> enough control variables or when these variables do not correlate well
> with the response variable during the learning period.
>
> The probability of obtaining this effect by chance is very small
> (Bayesian one-sided tail-area probability p = 0.031). This means the
> causal effect can be considered statistically significant.

Comment: Any source you could provide?

Comment: Oh, this is a summary produced by the CausalImpact R package. I guess the best I can do is provide the other results.

Comment: This question and answer over at Stack Overflow may help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46333588/6170115

Answer (score 3):

Two two statements actually refer to different tests:

- **The first statement refers to a two-sided test.** It checks whether a **95% CI** excludes zero (which in your case it doesn't). This means that if you're interested in whether there is any effect (whether positive or negative), your result is not significant.
- **The second statement refers to a one-sided test.** It checks whether a **90% CI** excludes zero (which in your case it does). In other words, if you're only testing for whether there is a (in your case) positive effect, your result is significant.

The intuition here is that a narrower hypothesis test buys you more statistical power. That said, to avoid confusion, we should probably highlight the distinction more clearly in the report or switch both statements to two-sided tests.